# How can I copy file from local server to remote with creating directories which absent via SSH?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scp

I can copy file via [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) by using [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) like this:

```
cd /root/dir1/dir2/
scp filename root@192.168.0.19:$PWD/
```

But if on remote server some directories are absent, in example remote server has only /root/ and havn't dir1 and dir2, then I can't do it and I get an error.

How can I do this - to copy file with creating directories which absent via SSH, and how to make it the easiest way?

The easiest way mean that I can get current path only by `$PWD`, i.e. script must be light moveable without any changes.

Comment: If you can use ssh you can do a `mkdir` non-interactively as seen in some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340048/how-do-i-create-a-directory-on-remote-host-if-it-doesnt-exist-without-ssh-ing-i

Comment: Look at `man scp` and check out the `-r` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can **make the same directories on the remote servers** and copy file to it via SSH by using SCP like this:

```
cd /root/dir1/dir2/
ssh -n root@192.168.0.19 "mkdir -p '$PWD'"
scp -p filename root@192.168.0.19:$PWD/
```

Answer (score 1):

This command will do it:

```
rsync -ahHv --rsync-path="mkdir -p $PWD && rsync" filename -e "ssh -v"  root@192.168.0.19:"$PWD/"
```